# How to stress and load test flash games like Mafia Wars, Farmville

Tags: php, flash, performance-testing

We're devoloping a flash game which have a php and mongodb backend.. It's kinda like FarmVille and other zynga games.
How can we make fully load test to cover possible performance issue earlier?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the flash client:**

Performance Testing Flash applications is not really possible since they are running on client machines and yo uhave no idea what kind of device/load level the client is experiencing.

What you should do for the Flash part is run it on the slowest platform you can find that supports flash (like a slow  android tablet) to see how it performs in low-grade systems and maybe improve some if your flash code. Also profiling the flash code will make the client faster and work better on slower devices/systems.

**For the server/backend:**

Write load and stress test cases that simulate the flash client. For more complex logic I suggest you use higher level languages to write the test cases (such as [LoadRunner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_LoadRunner)). If you can not afford LoadRunner or similar, then you could try [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) (free) or write your own app that acts like a client and spawn multiple of them (threads/processes) at the same time.

You should measure response times from the server/backend and also monitor CPU, Disk, Network etc. find out how your server performs under a certain load.

If you have a large number of simultaneous clients (over 500) then you should consider load-balancing the backend.. but that is another story and will increase your code-complexity considerably ([read more here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_%28computing%29))!

Answer (score 1):

You can't really stress test flash applications. You should write stress tests for your PHP code and maybe use one of the automatic testing applications at the same time(which is unnecessary if your PHP stress tests are good).
In order to test UI you can use FlexMonkey, RIATest or flash selenium in case of CI development.